# Context switch and the OS scheduler algorithm

Tags: operating-system, scheduler, context-switch

So the way I understand it when one process switches out for another a Kernel will save out the current state of a process and then a OS scheduler algorithm will choose the next process to swap in. Does this algorithm its self not need to be loaded in as it is a process? Does the kernel itself use CPU time when performing the switch if so How does the kernel get access to CPU cycles in amongst a context switch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the scheduler as the algorithm that's used to decide which process to run next. It can be run on the same core after a process is switched out of a core, and will choose the next process to be switched in.

Comment: thanks for your response so is the scheduler itself a process that must be switched in to choose the next process?